# Navigationbar title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my current project, my navigation controller title doesn't seem to update / change. To see what's wrong I've created a new project and embedded a navigation controller to the view controller.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print(navigationController) // Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7b356200>)

    navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Main"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

Strangely the navigation bar changes to green but still there is no title. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your line with this

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Main"
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I've made another empty project and strangely both of the methods works. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I was reading the docs about this. [scroll down to "The Middle Item" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/) to see ways to set the navigation controller title.

I believe that it worked for you the second time because you referenced the `ViewController` itself instead of the `UINavigationController`, as such:
`self.navigationItem.title = "Main"`

Comment: The strange thing is, I copied paste the exact same code... Weird.

Comment: I tried printing the title you set using your method to the console and I can see that it is set to **Main**, which means that the statement is working just fine, even though I don't see it as a title. Also the description from `navigationController?.navigationItem` is this: **The navigation item used to represent the view controller in a parent's navigation bar.** I don't know the difference between your first and second projects, but I thought this might give you a hint.

Comment: My original project is using container views, so that might explain it. The two test projects were both the same though (except the last one was newly created).